# Where is the wallpaper stored?

Tags: desktop-background

On Ubuntu 11.10, I go to a web page, right-click an image and set it as a desktop picture.

Now my question is I never saved or downloaded it. So where is it stored?

Comment: In home folder 
it will create a directory like .background

open the home folder and press ctrl+h to show the hiddenfiles

then you can see this folder

ps:i am not sure about answer 
thats why i posted here:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is usually saved in the home folder.

To find it, run the following command in a terminal:

```
find Firefox_wallpaper.png
```

Comment: I found the file you mentioned. And it is my current wallpaper. Then what happens if I change the wallpaper? Will it replace this existing file? If that's the case, I'll lose my file when a new wallpaper is set, isn't it?

Comment: If you change the wallpaper, the file will still be there.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but how will the older image stay in there when the file name is *Firefox_wallpaper.png* ?

Comment: Ah, wait. If you choose a new wallpaper from the browser, it will replace the existing file.